# QuerySelectorAll(input[type=select]) not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to select every other type of element on the page except:

```
var elems = querySelectorAll("input[type=select]");
```

Once I have them, I am applying `.disabled` in a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].disabled = true;
}
```

This works for all inputs except `<select>`.

Forgive me for this stupid question, but my search results, both here in SO, and on google, are flooded with false hits on "select" in "query**SELECT**orAll().

Does anyone know the correct syntax to use to select `select` elements?

Or, if my syntax is correct, why it is not working?

Comment: When you were selecting `<input type="thing">`, you used `input[type=thing]`. When you’re selecting `<select>`, you use `select`.

Comment: That was correct.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand the question, you can probably get all the elements you want with one query: `document.querySelectorAll("select,input")`. Your issue comes from the fact that a `select` and `input` element are separate elements and your query selector looks only for input tags. If you want only select tags use `document.querySelectorAll("select")`.

For more information about query selectors, you can read more about [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)(that's how `querySelectorAll` works.)